Heating Aluminium Block with 40W Cartridges
I want to heat 150x150x12.7mm aluminium block to 275 °C in 60 seconds.
Aluminium block is 780grams. I have 40 Watts ceramic cartridges. How many do i need to use to achive 275°C in 60 seconds?
I used a calculator online and it gave me 174915 joules needed for ΔT 250°C. I have 40 Watts cartridges which means they are 40 joules/sec
60 seconds is needed to give 174915 joules so every second 174915/60 joules needed which makes 2915.25 joules needed per second. Which results  i need roughly 72 cartridges. Is this calculation correct?
It makes me suspect because 72 comes to me way too many cartridges to achive the requirements.
Calculator Link

Cartridge Link


If 1) you have good enough thermal coupling that the heating element doesn't overheat, AND 2) the elements can withstand enough voltage across their terminals without arcing, AND 3) the wires are also big enough and well cooled enough to not melt from the required current, then you can dump far more power into them than what they're rated for.  That will reduce the number of elements needed, but you'd probably want to do it in a well-ventilated area away from flammable stuff, in case you have a false positive on one of those requirements.  Also don't expect to claim warranty or insurance...

This is more of a mechanical engineering/physics thing but I'll bite. You have 771g of aluminum. The specific heat capacity is 0.9 J per gram per degree. This means that increasing the temperature by 250°C will require 173 kJ. Over one minute, this is 2900 J/s, or 2.9 kW - I.e. just over 72 40-watt heaters. So yes, the calculator you used is correct: 250°C is pretty hot and heating a non-trivial amount of material to that temperature in one minute takes a lot of power.
This assumes the heat is uniformly absorbed by the block - and no losses (about 140 W in free air with the plate facing up). If you are using this block to heat something else up then you will need to take that into account, plus the thermal capacity of the heater itself. I would plan for at least 4 kW of heating capacity or even more to hit your metrics. With a suitable planar heater I think it might be possible. With cartridge heaters, they will only be in thermal contact with the sheet in a small tangential area so these are definitely not the right way to go about it.

And bear in mind that 2.9 kW is a bit less than twice what you can draw from a typical North American power circuit without tripping a breaker, and (I believe) pretty close to the limit in European circuits. If you expect to power this straight from mains, make sure to check that you have an appropriate power supply!

Thank you for your answer. I will go with reducing the thickness of aluminium and finding another powerfull heater element. Is clear that these cartridges are not usefull for reaching required temperature in 60  secs.

It's only suspect because you have relatively wimpy heaters and a fairly fast heating profile. I'm going to use Imperial measurements, since those are used by suppliers I know.
If you can drill 3/8" holes horizontally through the 1/2" plate (eg. for a platen) you would get roughly 7 square inches of surface area per heater. With 0.01" clearance about 150W/in^2 is the maximum acceptable for watt density, so you could get 1kW heaters 150mm x 9.5mm diameter, and you'd need about 4 of them, which should fit easily in the 150mm length. Alternatively, for better life use more of them with lower watts. Or maybe you need more plate strength and the heaters have to be smaller diameter, lower power and more of them.
Needless to say you need to limit the temperature or the heaters will melt the aluminum and then themselves fairly quickly.


Yes you are right, there will be also cooling effect from air and surroundings. And need to consider heat density too. Thank you for pointing it out.

The (surface) watt density governs what maximum power a given technology of heater can be manufactured. The higher the heating rate and the lower the maximum temperature the closer you can go to a simple adiabatic approximation ignoring or making a small allowance for losses. It's also a good idea to have some spare capacity for when mains voltage is a bit low or there is cold air or the starting temperature is lower. There are rules of thumb for how much capacity you want for a controlled temperature.
